# Why is this PHP function/MySQL database rounding down decimal values?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with some PHP code, which inserts the price of an item into a MySQL database. The price *is* being inserted, but it is always being rounded down.

For example, if I insert a figure of 9.99, it's being rounded down to 9.00 in the database.

I think that it's a problem with the PHP code, as I've inserted data manually with an sql statement in phpMyAdmin and the data is not being rounded down.

I used `item_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL` to create the column, so it should accept decimal places.

I've also used `echo` to check that the correct value is reaching the .php file from the html form, and a value with a decimal point is being displayed.

I'm defining the `$total` variable like so:

```php
// Is repeated across multiple functions
$price = test_input($_POST["price-2"]);
$total += $price
```

Here is the section of code which inserts the information into the database:

```php
echo $total; // Returns a decimal value (eg 9.99)

$sql = "INSERT INTO purchase_requests (submitted_by, request_type, summary, 
cost_centre, location, location_details, transport, total_price, approved, 
approver, paid) VALUES (?,'purchase',?,?,?,?,'false',?,'pending','pending','pending');";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
  echo "SQL Error";
} else {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issssi", $submitter, $summary, $costCentre,
  $location, $locationDetails, $total);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Can anyone understand why this might be occurring? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are telling PHP to save the value as integer, with this line of code:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issssi", $submitter, $summary, $costCentre, $location, $locationDetails, $total);
```

The `i` stands for "integer". If you wanna insert double values, you have to use the `d`.

In your case your line becomes:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issssd", $submitter, $summary, $costCentre, $location, $locationDetails, $total);
```